# Atmosphere Grails single user broadcast

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, atmosphere

I'm creating a Grails application which makes use of the Atmosphere plugin to push data to the browser. However I'm having trouble in creating a broadcast channel to a single user (the session's user). My code is has follows:

Service:

```
static atmosphere = [mapping: '/atmosphere/recommend']

def onRequest = { event ->
    def request = event.request
    def response = event.response

    event.suspend()     

    def broadcaster = event.broadcaster
    request.session.broadcaster = broadcaster
    broadcaster.broadcasterConfig.addFilter(new XSSHtmlFilter())     
}

def onStateChange = { event ->

    if (!event.message) return

    event.resource.response.writer.with {
        write "<script>parent.callback('${event.message}');</script>"
        flush()
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
def builder = new JSONBuilder()
    def jsonResult = builder.build{
                            artist = artistInstance
                            location = {
                                lat = eventInstance.location.lat
                                lng = eventInstance.location.lng
                            }
                        }

session.broadcaster.broadcast(jsonResult)
```

This solution broadcasts the jsonResult to every user. What I want to achieve is to broadcast only for the current user.
Any ideas?
If you need more details just let me know.

Thanks

Comment: looks like this is similar to what you want no ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543831/unable-to-broadcast-to-single-connection-using-atmosphere-runtime

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you can use session to share the onRequest's event.

```
request.session[userId]=event
```

then in controller :

```
broadcast(jsonResult,session[userId])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your events in grails, you can filter out cients by using a browserFilter closure.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can make use of the `uuid` which is assigned to each Atmosphere Resource.
To retrieve the suspended uuid based on an Atmosphere Request you can do:

`String suspendedUUID = (String)req.getAttribute(ApplicationConfig.SUSPENDED_ATMOSPHERE_RESOURCE_UUID);`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the session

```
session.broadcaster.broadcast(jsonResult, AtmosphereResource)
```

See this [API](http://atmosphere.github.io/atmosphere/apidocs/org/atmosphere/cpr/Broadcaster.html#broadcast%28java.lang.Object,%20org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource%29).

(I am Atmosphere's creator).